# How to use element.offsetBottom?

Tags: javascript, offset

So I was working on making a sticky nav once you scroll past the hero. I've had no issues using `element.offsetTop` before. But I'm trying to find a way to do it for the bottom of the element. `element.offsetBottom` doesn't seem to be a thing. So is there a way to track the bottom on an element in JS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`element.offsetTop` is a distance from the element to the nearest positioned `element.offsetParent`.

So if you want to calculate the distance from `element.offsetParent` to element bottom edge, if I understand you correctly, you can just

```
element.offsetBottom = element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight
```

Comment: This is such an elegant solution. It's funny how a lot of the time the solution is just staring you straight in the face. We really do have a tendency to overthink things sometimes lol.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the previous answer which pointed me in the right direction to figure this out for my application.
Since bottom is measured UP from the bottom of the parent to the bottom of the element, use the offset height of the parent, minus the offset top of the element, minus its height also:

```
var bottomY = element.offsetParent.offsetHeight - element.offsetTop - element.offsetHeight;
```

So if the parent was `100px` tall, and the element was `10px` tall with a `bottom:20px` position, the offset top would be 70 - subtract that and the element's own `10px` height from the the parent's 100 to get back to the 20, or to determine its new bottom position if it's been moved and has a new offset top.

This is currently working to move thumbnails set to `bottom:0` at the end of a `100vh` container down out of the way and back up again, after also converting to vw units in my case since the thumbnails are scaled that way.